# Writing OO Javascript with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, design-patterns, prototypejs

I come from a Prototype JS background where OO Javascript is encouraged through the use of `Class.create()`. Now I am doing some JQuery work and I am trying to write some properly structured JQuery code where I can, for example, call the same object function from two different click event handlers.

Here is the code in Prototype:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {

    // create document
    APP.pageHelper = new APP.PageHelper();


});

// namespace our code
window.APP = {};

// my class
APP.PageHelper = Class.create({

  // automatically called
  initialize: function(name, sound) {
    this.myValue = "Foo";

    // attach event handlers, binding to 'this' object
    $("myButton").observe("click", this.displayMessage.bind(this))

  },

  displayMessage: function() {
    console.log("My value: " + this.myValue); // 'this' is the object not the clicked button!
  }

});
```

I am wondering how the following code can be replicated in JQuery where there is no way to bind a function call to the object it is called in, and 'this' is always the element clicked.

I have heard of a way to do it the Douglas Crockford 'module' pattern (http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) but I would love if someone could show me how you would implement the code above using JQuery and that pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question... I am a mootools guy myself, where you have the `Class` object and `bind` method to accomplish this pattern.  In jQuery, `bind` means something else entirely!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Writing jquery in an object oriented way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980354/jquery-writing-jquery-in-an-object-oriented-way)

Comment: jQuery and OO are unrelated. If you really want to use Javascript OO, you won't use jQuery =) jQuery is not a 'OO build classes' framework; it's a DOM+events+animations shizzle framework. If you want to add events, shuffle a few html nodes and show dancing unicorns, don't do it OO style: do it simple and readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely bind an event to something other then the dom element. Just use `$.proxy`.

### Description:

Takes a function and returns a new one that will always have a particular context.
version added: 1.4

```
 /**
  * @param function - The function whose context will be changed.
  * @param context - The object to which the context (this) of the function should be set.
  */
jQuery.proxy( function, context )
```

This method is most useful for attaching event handlers to an element where the context is pointing back to a different object. Additionally, jQuery makes sure that even if you bind the function returned from jQuery.proxy() it will still unbind the correct function if passed the original.

Comment: Super, this is really what I needed. Great to know that exists and avoid the `bind()` confusion. I wrote up a quick explanation so that others can see the original example in my question ported to JQuery: http://flydillonfly.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/writing-oo-javascript-using-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the sharing the link. I am happy I was able to help.

Answer (score 4):

I roll my own objects based on this good article:

http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/

I just choose whichever pattern makes sense for the project I'm working on.  So like a quick example to do what you're asking would be:

```
$.myNamespace.myClass = function (options) {
    this.settings = $.extend({ ... defaults ... }, options);
    this.init();
};
$.myNamespace.myClass.prototype.settings = {
    someValue: 'default',
    someSelector: '#myButton'
};
$.myNamespace.myClass.prototype.init = function () {
    var self = this;
    $(self.settings.someSelector).click(function (event) {
        console.log(self.settings.someValue);
    });
};
```

You responded below that you knew about prototype but the syntax is a bit annoying.  I think that's just a matter of being used to one syntax over another.  I'm sure the Prototype library makes use of closures and .prototype just like I did above and like some other answers suggest below.  In the end, just write syntax that you feel comfortable with.  The suggestion to use Coffee Script is cool too - whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: sorry, I think I read too quickly.  I wrote some quick sample code above. (I assumed my usual jQuery namespacing trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527089/is-it-possible-to-create-a-namespace-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Class.create()` to write classes in javascript.

```
APP.PageHelper = function(name, sound) { // this is the constructor
    this.myValue = "Foo";
    // attach event handlers, binding to 'this' object
    $('#myButton').click($.proxy(this.displayMessage, this)); // use $.proxy instead of `bind`
}
APP.PageHelper.prototype = { // define more prototype functions here
    displayMessage: function() {
        console.log("My value: " + this.myValue); // 'this' is the object not the clicked button!
    }
};
```

Now for more complicated classes with inheritance I use John Resig's [simple class inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).

I also separate classes into files, wrapped with a closure. This would be `PageHelper.js`:

```
;!!window['APP'] && (function (NS, $) {
    NS.PageHelper = Class.extend({ // see link above
        // functions
        init: function () { // constructor

        },
        displayMessage: function() { 

        }
    });
})(window['APP'], jQuery);
```

Comment: I am aware of the regular way to use write classes using `.prototype`. You don't *need* `Class.create()` but if you are using Prototype it is nice and convenient.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a somewhat similar OOP structure for JQuery, you might try http://code.google.com/p/jquery-klass/

It's what I use.

Answer (score 0):

I find writing [OO code in CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#classes) to be much more pleasant than `Class.create()` or lower level `prototype` stuff. Check out the section on [function binding](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#fat_arrow).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best jQuery Class implementation is from John Resig's blog (http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). I highly recommend it; it's very similar to Prototype JS.

I wrote a library on top of it to make OO design easy within jQuery ( https://github.com/arturnt/brickjs ). For example, in order to do what you are doing there you can do the following.

`Comp.APP = {};
Comp.APP.PageHelper = Comp.extend({
    init: function(e) {
        this._super(e);
        this.myValue = "foo";
    },
    "#myButton click": function() {
        console.log(this.myValue); //prints
    }
});`